# MySQL Command not found after editing bash_profile

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal

I have been trying to run mysql after successfully installing it. but keeps saying command not found. I added the following line on my *.bash_profile* file :
`export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/`

My complete *.bash_profile* file:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Comment: Maybe it should be `/usr/local/mysql/bin`?

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked when i uninstalled and tried reinstalled (I suspect i might have installed an older version of mysql)